# wp how to exclude filter from the custom query

Tags: wordpress, filter, slug

I am trying to exclude a filter (slug) from a loop. I am researched exclude and have tried it in various places in the code. Usually I break the page. This is the code, I am attempting to change to exclude the slug 20. It is a filter named 'american'. I have tried to exclude at the beginning of the array, didn't work; then, I tried after the foreach($catz as $cat) section. I tried this ‘exclude=20&title_li=' . I tried cat=-20 and various other combinations. Any help would be very very appreciated.

```
// The Custom Query
 $args = array(
'post_type'         => 'portfolio',
'posts_per_page'    => $counter_folio,
'paged'             => $paged,
'order'             => 'DESC'

 );
 query_posts( $args );
 while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
 $color = substr(get_option('dcb_dynamic_color'), 1);
 // Get the original thumbnail of the post
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), false, '' );
$excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
// Get the custom fields
$vimeo = get_post_meta($post->ID, "vimeo", true);
$youtube = get_post_meta($post->ID, "youtube", true);
// Get the filter > Category of item
$catz = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID,'filters');
foreach($catz as $cat){ 
    $currcat = $cat->slug;
    $catname = $cat->name;
    break;
}
$counter++;
?>
```

Comment: please do not use `query_posts` is bad for querying data, its problematic and not reliable. Use `WP_Query` instead, you will have more control over your data and peace of mind :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the post with id 20 simple exclude it with the following code

```
    // The Custom Query
     $args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'portfolio',
    'posts_per_page'    => $counter_folio,
    'paged'             => $paged,
    'order'             => 'DESC'

     );
     query_posts( $args );
     while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
     $color = substr(get_option('dcb_dynamic_color'), 1);
    // Get the original thumbnail of the post
   $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), false, '' );
   $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
   // Get the custom fields
   $vimeo = get_post_meta($post->ID, "vimeo", true);
   $youtube = get_post_meta($post->ID, "youtube", true);
   // Get the filter > Category of item
   $catz = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID,'filters');
   foreach($catz as $cat){ 
    if($cat->slug != 'american')
    {
      $currcat = $cat->slug;
      $catname = $cat->name;
      break;
     }
    }
    $counter++;
```

Comment: Thank you. That is the spot I have been trying the exclude. I put your code in place, but it didn't work; however, it didn't break the page either..which is what my code continually did.

Comment: I think it has to be: if a post has this slug exclude it. And then exclude name.

Comment: Well, I added $exclude=get_cat_ID('american'); instead of the if.. and it worked, but now I still have the title_li to deal with.